# In automobiles, are we using the car chassis as a ground terminal of battery? Then why we don't get shocked while touching it?

Tags: power-supply

My concern is to know if we can use the metallic chassis for a replacement of ground wire.

In automobiles, the positive wire is taken to the headlamps and ground is provided by connecting the neutral wire to chassis of car.

Comment: (1) Would you get a shock if you touched both terminals on the 12 V battery? (2) If you touch the chassis where would the current flow to? (3) Why are there no capital letters and punctuation in your post?

Comment: As return current is flowing through the chassis and I touched its metallic body with hand, at that time I am providing a different path to earth ground so why don't i get shocked ?

Comment: Draw a picture of the path you think the current would take. Add it into your question using the edit link. Remember that current flows in a loop so try to draw the arrows in your diagram. Why do you think that current would flow from the chassis to earth?

Comment: What kind of material is used for construction of chassis , how much conductive is that ? Can you please suggest any document or link for automotive electronics

Comment: "*What kind of material is used for construction of chassis?*" Why are you asking this? Is it not obvious? "*How much conductive is that?*" If you answer the first question you can look up the resistivity or conductivity of that material on the web. "*Can you please suggest any document or link for automotive electronics.*" No. I don't have any. I notice you have not answered any of my questions to you in the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

To get a shock requires a sufficient current through the body. That requires a few things.

Firstly under normal circumstances you need enough voltage to break through the skin barrier. How much voltage this is does vary depending on circumstances but the normal rule is under dry conditions voltages up to about 50 volts are considered safe to touch.

Secondly (ignoring static electricity which does lead to shocks but they are too short in duration to be dangerous to the body and ignoring capacitie coupling which is not relevant at DC) current normally flows in loops. No part of the cars electrical system is deliberately connected to the earth, so when you touch the cars body and the earth at the same time there is really nowhere for current to go. The voltage between different parts of the cars chassis will normally be a small fraction of the (already low enough to be safe) battery voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Most cars built with metal chassis or metal bodies use the chassis / body for the return to the battery.

This saves on wire and weight and of course, cost.

Comment: how much current can be allowed to pass through it ? Is there any regulations on it ?

Comment: The maximum current flow through the chassis is the highest necessary for the devices to function, so the highest current is probably that required for the starter. That current will be a lot lower than the maximum possible the chassis can support without excessive heating.

Comment: And the starter often has a dedicated ground wire, FWIW.

Comment: @duskwuff it’s also the ground engine : body and engine : battery and body : battery so for all returns not only starter.

Comment: Is this principal also followed in electric cars to reduce the no. of wires to the -ve battery terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

If you tied the +12 volts to the earth, you might feel 12 volts across your body by standing with bare feet on the dirt and then licking (with your tongue) a bare part of the car's chassis.

Comment: Tasty, tasty automobiles.